# Permutations: Speed up, predict and/or multithread

Tags: r, multithreading, algorithm, optimization, permutation

I'm working on an algorithm, which needs to bruteforce N tests successively. The permutation of the tests is important for the outcome.

Problem:
When some rules apply, I need to be able to restrict the combinatoric search space. For example:

Permutation "1,2,3" renders following tests useless. So I don't need permutations like "1,2,3,4" or "1,2,3,5" etc anymore. So I wrote some code, to do permutations by myself, but I'ts slow.

What can I do to make this code faster? Or is there a package out there I missed?
Should I implement this in C myself? Is there an easy way to multithread this? Is there an easy way to predict the Nth permutation? (This would be neat, to implement parallel computing the easy way ;)

Thank you very much!
Marc

```
# Example of permu.with.check.
# 02.05.2014; Marc Giesmann

# Set if needed Recursion limit
# options(expressions=1e5)

permu.with.check <- function(perm = c(1,2,3), current = NULL, fun){

  #Optional: Calculate all variants
  #if(is.null(current)){
  #  all.permutations <- 2* (sum(gamma(perm + 1)) - 1)
  #}

  for(i in 1: length(perm)){

    fix  <- perm[i]   # calculated elements; fix at this point
    rest <- perm[-i]  # elements yet to permutate

    #If this is a recursive call, use
    #"current" to complement current fix value
    if(!is.null(current)){
      fix <- c(current,fix)
    }

    #Call callback.
    #If callback returns "FALSE" don't calculate 
    #further permutations with this "fix". Skip i.
    if(fun(x=fix)){

      #if this is the call with the last
      #value (the deepest,recursive call), stop recursion
      if(length(rest) > 0){
        permu.with.check( rest, fix,fun ) #recursive. 
      }
    }
  }

}

# Callback for permu.with.check
# Ignores 3
perm.callback <- function(x){

  #CALCULATE STUFF HERE
  #cat(counter, ". permutation: ",x, "\n")
  counter <<- counter + 1

  #TEST - EXAMPLE:
  # if new number equals 3, we don't need further testing
  if(x[length(x)] == 3){
    return(FALSE)
  }else{
    return(TRUE)
  }

} 

########## MAIN ################

counter <- 0
permu.with.check(perm=1:8, fun=perm.callback)

#Compare with permutations from package Combinations
# counter (from permu.with.check) == 27399
# nrow(permutations(8))           == 40320

#OPTIONAL: Try out Combinations package
#if(!require(Combinations)){
#  install.packages("Combinations", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
#  require(Combinations)
#}

#nrow(permutations(8))
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling your functions to find bottle necks?

Comment: Good idea! Didn't know, there was a built in profiler in R. The "tail(x, n = 1)" made it slow (~ 46 seconds for 1:10). With "x[length(x)]" it's ~7 seconds for 1:10. Wow! Thank you! Do you have any feedback for my implementation? I am neither a R- professional, nor a mathematician... ;)

Comment: Marc, @RomanLuštrik's comment is the crux of it. If the bottleneck is in the test function then the method of determining the conditional design of experiments is generally not a problem computationally. Further questions: how many levels in your permutation? Are you looking to exhaust the number of levels? (I have a mechanism for iterating through first 3 then filtered 4 then filtered 5 of a 5+ level permutation test, but it assumes your test is more expensive.)

Comment: With rare exceptions often having to do with cache organization, multithreading gives you at most an n-times speedup where n is the number of physical processors. It's probably not the best use of your time when it's likely that there are much larger algorithmic improvements to be obtained that are specific to your pruning rules.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Exactly. I want to have the cake AND eat it. With the "Combinations"package I have singlecored ~758000 calculations per second. With my algorhithm which is able to prune intelligently, i only have ~243000. Pruning is important, but I need both. If there would be a way to "teach" the Combination package my pruning-method. A parallel version would be the frosting on my cake ;)

Comment: What does `perm.callback` actually do then? It's difficult to design a good enumeration strategy without this knowledge.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I have testdata, and computer generated tests. Every generated permutation represents a set of tests. So I use the permutation-vector to do something like this: alltests[current.permutation]. With this list I generate a conclusion, which tries to predict my testdata. But if a permutation of 3 tests (e.g. test1,test14,test2) has a prediction for all testdata already, another test wouldn't do anything, because there is nothing left to predict. So If I have a permutation of 1:15, and test1,test14,test2 predict everything, I don't need the following permutations anymore.

Comment: Is the order of the tests meaningful?

Comment: Yes! If testA predicts 1:100 of 120 datasets, and testB 90:120, there are 10 tests (90:100) which can change the overall outcome, when the order is the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Marc, based on your recent comment, here is a suggested implementation.

This is a very iterative solution, and not hugely efficient as far as
producing the permutations. It assumes that the computation in
`testfunc` is much more expensive than the permutation generation.

Basic setup:

```
set.seed(123)
opts <- 1:5
library(combinat)
## a little inefficient but functional
permn.lim <- function(x, m=length(x)) {
    tmp <- permn(x)
    if (m >= length(x)) tmp
    else unique(lapply(tmp, `[`, 1:m))
}
testfunc <- function(...) list(results=list(), continue=(runif(1) < 0.3))
```

Run the first iteration of 3-tuples.

```
doe3 <- permn.lim(opts, 3)
length(doe3)
## [1] 60
str(head(doe3, n=2))
## List of 2
##  $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
##  $ : int [1:3] 1 2 5
tmp3 <- lapply(doe3, testfunc)
str(head(tmp3, n=2))
## List of 2
##  $ :List of 2
##   ..$ results : list()
##   ..$ continue: logi TRUE
##  $ :List of 2
##   ..$ results : list()
##   ..$ continue: logi FALSE
results3 <- sapply(tmp3, function(zz) zz$results)
continue3 <- sapply(tmp3, function(zz) zz$continue)
head(continue3, n=2)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE
length(doe3.continue <- doe3[continue3])
## [1] 19
```

`results3` is a list of each actual test result (allegedly captured in
`testfunc`), and `continue3` is a vector of bools indicating if
continued work with that respective 3-tuple is justified. For lookup
purposes , we then filter `doe3` into `doe3.continue`.

We then generate the next series of experiments (4, in this case), and
filter that based on the successful tests from the previous, as stored
in `doe3.continue`.

```
doe4.all <- permn.lim(opts, 4)
length(doe4.all)
## [1] 120
doe4.filtered <- Filter(function(zz) list(zz[1:3]) %in% doe3.continue, doe4.all)
length(doe4.filtered)
## [1] 38
tmp4 <- lapply(doe4.filtered, testfunc)
results4 <- sapply(tmp4, function(zz) zz$results)
continue4 <- sapply(tmp4, function(zz) zz$continue)
doe4.continue <- doe4[continue4]
length(doe4.continue)
## [1] 35
```

This process can be repeated for as many elements are in `opts`. If
this is for a fixed number of levels, then it's not hard to maintain
in the current form. If you will be repeating this with different
numbers of levels, then it wouldn't be too hard to make this a
tail-recursive function, perhaps a little more refined.

Comment: Thank you for your code! As far as I can see it, you heavily rely on "permn" from the combinat- package. The combinat package is, when confonted with permutations larer than 10 a desaster. I tried to use it's callback-feature, but it instabilized my box (it seems, like it preallocates a matrix, which is a bad idea when it comes to permutations >= 15). I will analyse your code later. In terms of multithreading or permutation-prediciton: What makes your code fast/more efficient/better than mine? Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Not certain it is, frankly ... I misread your post and thought you were asking for functional code, not code better than yours, sorry. I do not have much experience with `combinat` and `permn` since my DOEs are generally satisfied with `combn` and `expand.grid`.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed: Permutation algorithm, with callback, which can decide

1. if permutation can be pruned at this point
2. if permutation should be saved

**and**

1. is capable of multithreading.

What I've got so far is a complicated code with redundancys but it works pretty okay so far.
I'm still not satisfied, because in multithreadingmode there is no way of giving feedback to the user. Here is my code, hopefully someone can reuse it.

If someone has an idea how to optimize it, PLEASE go on. I'm still not sure, if my ideas about global/partly global variables work correctly.

Attached Code is a working example which prunes if "3" is the last number in the current permutation, and only saves, if the sum of the digits of the current permutation is the highest at this point. Downside of multithreading: It saves many redundant values, because the "highest sum of digits" can't be shared along the threads, which is VERY unfortunate at this point.

Regards,
Marc

```
  # Example of permu.new
  # 05.05.2014; Marc Giesmann

  # Set if needed Recursion limit
  # options(expressions=1e5)
  require(compiler)
  compilePKGS(enable=TRUE)
  enableJIT(3)

  require(doMC)

  CONST_SKIP <- 1
  CONST_SAVE <- 2
  CONST_VAL  <- 3

  #--------------------- 

  permu.new <- function(perm,fun, values = 0, savemax = 1000){

    #DEFINE INTERNAL FUNCTIONS
    permu.worker.save.max   <- savemax
    permu.worker.save.count <- 1

    permu.worker.global.savelist <- vector(mode="list",length = permu.worker.save.max)

    #Saves permutation. If there are more to save than in savemax defined,
    #it primitlively appends a entry to the list
    permu.worker.save <- function(permutation, values){
      if(permu.worker.save.count > permu.worker.save.max){
        permu.worker.global.savelist[[length(permu.worker.global.savelist)+1]] <<- list(perm=permutation,values=values)
      }else{
        permu.worker.global.savelist[[permu.worker.save.count]] <<- list(perm=permutation,values=values)
      }
      permu.worker.save.count <<- permu.worker.save.count + 1 
    }

    #CREATES RESULTOBJECT
    robj <- function(vals){
      return(vector(mode="numeric",length=2+vals))
    }

    #WORKERBEE. Does the funpart of recursion and calling the callbacks
    permu.worker <- function(perm, current, resultobject, fun){
      #resultobject<- robj.reset(resultobject)  #reset internal values.
      resultobject[1:2] <- 0 #reset internal values.

      for(i in 1: length(perm)){

        fix  <- c(current,perm[i])   # calculated elements; fix at this point
        rest <- perm[-i]  # elements yet to permutate

        #Call callback.
        resultobject <- fun(x=fix, resultobject = resultobject)

        #Save permutation?
        if(resultobject[CONST_SAVE]){
          permu.worker.save(fix, resultobject[CONST_VAL])
        }

        #if this is the call with the last
        #value (the deepest,recursive call) or object wanted
        #to skip next iterations stop recursion
        if(length(rest) && !resultobject[CONST_SKIP]){
          resultobject <- permu.worker(rest, fix, resultobject, fun)
        } 
      }#end for

      return(resultobject)
    }

    #DEFINE INTERNAL END
    #BEGIN FUNCTION
    resultobject <- robj(values) #vector(mode="numeric", length=2+values)

    #for(i in 1: length(perm)){
    i<-0
    res<-foreach(i=1: length(perm), .combine=c) %dopar% {
        #calculate the first permutation manually
        resultobject <- permu.worker(perm[i], NULL, resultobject, fun)

        #now do the funny, recursive stuff
        resultobject <- permu.worker(perm[-i], perm[i], resultobject, fun)

        # Now we're ready for the next permutation.
        # Save all the things we need
        return(permu.worker.global.savelist[1:permu.worker.save.count-1])

    }#end foreach

  return(res) 
  }

  #----------------------------------------------------------------
  #EXAMPLE CALLBACK
  # Prunes, if 3 is last number in permutation
  # Saves only, if sum() of permutation is the highes found yet.
  # IMPORTANT: return has to be a "resultobject", which is provided
  # through the parameters. 
  # Use 
  # resultobject[CONST_SKIP] <- TRUE/FALSE (prune after this permutation T/F)
  # resultobject[CONST_SAVE] <- TRUE/FALSE (return this permutation, save it T/F)
  # resultobject[CONST_VAL]  <- NUMERIC (use this to save something for the process)
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------
  perm.callback <- function(x,resultobject){

    #CALCULATE STUFF HERE;
    #Example a global counter;(works only singlethreaded)
    counter <<- counter + 1

    #SKIP EXAMPLE
    #Skip this one? skip next permutations if the last number is 3
    resultobject[CONST_SKIP] <- (x[length(x)] == 3)

    if(resultobject[CONST_SKIP]){
      #another global counter (works only singlethreaded)
      skipped <<- skipped + 1 
    }

    #SAVE EXAMPLE
    #Should we save this permutation?
    #Save only, if sum of permutation is bigger than own value 
    s <- sum(x)
    if(s > resultobject[CONST_VAL]){
      resultobject[CONST_VAL]  <- s
      resultobject[CONST_SAVE] <-TRUE

      #yet another example-counter. (works only singlethreaded)
      saved <<- saved + 1 
    }else{
      resultobject[CONST_SAVE] <-FALSE
    }

    return(resultobject)
  }


  #---------- MAIN
  #counter/skipped/saved are working in singlethreading mode,
  #See usage in perm.callback().
  #
  #Variables show, how many...
  counter <- 0 # ...permutations have been calculated 
  skipped <- 0 # ... have been skipped (last digit was 3)
  saved   <- 0 # ... were saved and returned

  #registerDoMC(4) #uncomment for multithreading
  stime <- system.time(gcFirst = TRUE, expr ={
  result <- permu.new(perm=1:10, fun=perm.callback,values=1)
  })
  cat(as.double(stime[3]), "seconds; ~", (counter / as.double(stime[3])), " calculations/second")
```